# How do I disable vsync in CCSM and Catalyst Control Center?

Tags: compiz, ati, fglrx

How do I disable vsync in Compiz-Config Settings Manager and Catalyst Control Center?

Answer (score 2):

In [ccsm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) - opengl plugin it is in there.

Comment: Worked great in 11.10 and Catalyst 11.11, thanks.