# Performance problems with FGLRX driver

Tags: graphics, performance, fglrx, radeon, gnome-classic

I have moved from ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 today and I am not impressed. I expected more in this version.
There is some improvement but also many bugs.

It works very slow for me. Graphic is very very slow. I have installed **ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver** but it is still slow.

How to fix graphic problems??

Comment: For classic, use this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic/63315#63315

Comment: I improved graphic performance by changing openGL settings in ccsm. classic desktop sucks in 11.10...

Comment: 1. unstable
 2. slow
 3. without ubuntu classic

I expected more in this version.
I am moving back (11.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an ATI 4770 and 11.10 works reasonably well for me.
As soon as the installer finishes, it leaves you with the open source driver. Which works better than the proprietary for the most things, but performs badly with games.

Then an icon appears to tell you there are proprietary drivers available. After that is installed, moving windows around starts to appear to be slow. Install ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager) and turn off v-sync in OpenGL tab to fix it.

- [How do I disable vsync in CCSM and Catalyst Control Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34261/how-do-i-disable-vsync-in-ccsm-and-ccc)

Comment: Disabling vsync in Compiz Config is a must. This one is such a terrible gotcha.

Comment: Thanks but I am on 11.04 again and works great!

Answer (score 0):

Folks,

i think there is a solution right here for amd drivers Radeon HD 2xxx - 4xxx for Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal.

Just check the lauchpad: [AMD Catalyst Legacy](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx)

For ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 you need to upgrade your graphic drivers and install the Catalyst 12.6 drivers, usually known as legacy.

But if tou want to upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 this is the solution. It works like a charm to me!
Hope this helps.

Best Regards